# Configuring Apache as a reverse proxy for HTTPS to HTTP for a containerised API on a VPS with cPanel

Tags: docker, apache, cpanel, vps

I have a c# Web API that is containerised using Docker. My react from end is hosted on HTTPS and I purchased a SSL certificate from NameCheap. My Container is running on http and I can successfully hit the endpoint in postman via
`http://www.example.com:8080/api/messages/health`

Following this information https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/modify-apache-virtual-hosts-with-include-files/,
I have set a userdata/include.conf file as the below

```
ServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "/var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/example.com/combined"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/cpanel/ssl/cpanel/certificate.pem"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8080/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

I have run these commands

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd
```

but I get a 404 when I call the endpoint via https
`https://www.example.com/api/messages/health`
but still get a 200 when calling http
`http://www.example.com:8080/api/messages/health`.

The `access.logs` don't provide any useful information

`[23/Jul/2023:05:43:45 +0000] "GET /api/messages/health HTTP/1.1" 404 23 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3"`